# Python: Dividing a column in one data frame with another with a cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 data frames as shown below. I need a resultant data which has the cumulative sums of periods of data frame 1 divided by cumulative sum of periods of data frame 2 in python indexed at pin, site and department.

### Dataframe 1:

```
 Pin    Site    Department   Period1     Period2     Period3     Period4

 1001     L       42           1           0           2           3
 1003     L       42           4           4           3           4
 1002     R       45           4           5           2           4
```

### Dataframe 2:

```
Pin     Site    Department  Period1          Period2    Period3    Period4 

1002      R           45          5            6           5           5 
1003      L           42          4            5           6           8 
1001      L           42          1            2           4           5
```

### Output

```
 Pin    Site    Department  Period1      Period2       Period3         Period4
 1001     L        42          1/1     (1+0)/(1+2)  (1+0+2)/(1+2+4) (1+0+2+3)/(1+2+4+5)
 1002     R        45          4/5     (4+5)/(5+6)  (4+5+2)/(5+6+5) (4+5+2+4)/(5+6+5+5)
 1003     L        42          4/4     (4+4)/(4+5)  (4+4+3)/(4+5+6) (4+4+3+4)/(4+5+6+8)
```

Irrespective of the order of the pins in both the dataframe I need the resultant data frame as above. The number of periods would increase month on month.

Comment: Are the Pin, Site, & Department columns guaranteed to be identical across dataFrames?

Comment: ^ if yes, then you may try `df1.iloc[:, 3:].cumsum(axis=1).div(df2.iloc[:, 3:].cumsum(axis=1))`

Comment: The order may change from data frame 1 and 2. But each pin will have unique site and department.

Comment: If the order changes, how are you supposed to map data from one to the other? Also, don't you think that is important information you neglected to mention in your question? If someone had decided to make that assumption and answer your question, they'd have wasted both their time and yours. Please add all relevant information to your question, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have changed the question as suggested.

Comment: No worries. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for align indices in division by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), last add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
df11 = df1.set_index(['Pin','Site','Department']).cumsum(axis=1)
df22 = df2.set_index(['Pin','Site','Department']).cumsum(axis=1)

df = df11.div(df22).reset_index()
print (df)
    Pin Site  Department  Period1   Period2   Period3   Period4
0  1001    L          42      1.0  0.333333  0.428571  0.500000
1  1002    R          45      0.8  0.818182  0.687500  0.714286
2  1003    L          42      1.0  0.888889  0.733333  0.652174
```

EDIT:

For filter out values `>1` need invert condition - keep alues `<=1` - compare and check if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) `True`s per rows:

```
df = df11.div(df22)
df = df[(df <= 1).all(axis=1)].reset_index()
```

Comment: @jezrael Thanks a lotss!! The code worked super fine!!

Comment: @jezrael Done!! Once again, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @jezrael Just in addition to the output, i want to remove rows which has value in any Period > 1. Can you please help me out with that?